# An inequality involving quantum channels

Tags: quantum-operation, probability

Consider two quantum circuits $\mathsf{C}$ and $\mathsf{D}$ applied to $|0^n\rangle$. Then, measure in the standard basis and, for $x \in \{0, 1\}^n$, consider two probabilities:

\begin{equation}
p_{x, \mathsf{C}} = \text{Tr}\left(|x\rangle \langle x | \mathsf{C} |0^n\rangle \langle 0^n | \mathsf{C}^{*}\right),~~~p_{x, \mathsf{D}} = \text{Tr}\left(|x\rangle \langle x | \mathsf{D} |0^n\rangle \langle 0^n | \mathsf{D}^{*} \right).
\end{equation}

For every $x$, let
\begin{equation}
p_{x, \mathsf{C}} \leq p_{x, \mathsf{D}}.
\end{equation}

Then, let $\Phi$ be a single qubit channel. Consider

\begin{equation}
q_{x, \mathsf{C}} = \text{Tr}\big(|x\rangle \langle x | \Phi^{\otimes n} (\mathsf{C} |0^n\rangle \langle 0^n | \mathsf{C}^{*}) \big),~~~q_{x, \mathsf{D}} = \text{Tr}\big(|x\rangle \langle x | \Phi^{\otimes n}(\mathsf{D} |0^n\rangle \langle 0^n | \mathsf{D}^{*}) \big).
\end{equation}

Is it true in general that
$$q_{x, \mathsf{C}} \leq q_{x, \mathsf{D}}?$$

If not, when is this true?

Comment: How can your condition on the probabilities not be just trivially an equality for all $x$?

Comment: In general, why should it be an equality? I agree equality is a special case.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood the condition, I agree with @Rammus. Suppose there is a $x'$ such that the inequality is strict, that is $p_{x',\mathsf{C}}<p_{x',\mathsf{D}}$. Summing the inequalities, you first get:
$$\sum_{x\neq x'}p_{x,\mathsf{C}}\leqslant\sum_{x\neq x'}p_{x,\mathsf{D}}$$
Adding the final $x'$ term:
$$\sum_{x}p_{x,\mathsf{C}}<\sum_{x}p_{x,\mathsf{D}}$$
However, both of these sums must equal $1$, hence the contradiction.

Comment: Intuitively, suppose you start from $p_{x,\mathsf{C}}=p_{x,\mathsf{D}}$ for all $x$. Now suppose you want to have a strict inequality on some $x'$. Since both these distributions must sum to $1$, it means that you have to decrease $p_{x'',\mathsf{D}}$ for some $x''$, which means $p_{x'',\mathsf{C}}\leqslant p_{x'',\mathsf{D}}$ no longer holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple counterexample: let $\mathsf{C}$ be the circuit that applies $H$ while $\mathsf{D}$ is the circuit that applies $HX$. That is, $\mathsf{C}$ creates $|+\rangle$ while $\mathsf{D}$ creates $|-\rangle$.

It is easily seen that $p_{b,\mathsf{C}}=p_{b,\mathsf{D}}$ for any bit $b$. However, let us consider $\Phi$ to be the channel that applies $H$. Then $q_{0,\mathsf{C}}=1$ and $q_{0,\mathsf{D}}=0$, thus the conjecture does not hold.

---

More generally, as mentioned in the comments, the condition $p_{x,\mathsf{C}}\leqslant p_{x,\mathsf{D}}$ for all $x$ is actually equivalent to $p_{x,\mathsf{C}}=p_{x,\mathsf{D}}$. Similarly, the condition that you want to be true is equivalent to the fact that all the probabilities are equal. However, as seen above, you can easily find maps that use the argument of the amplitudes (in the example, $0$ and $\pi$) to change this.

Thus, I don't think there is a general result that can be written here. At most, if $\Phi$ does not take the arguments of the amplitudes into account (that is, it only affects the modulus of the amplitudes), then the property you've written is true.